# One instance vs multiple instances .NET framework

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, memory, time

Currently, I have designed an application, whenever a particular event is triggered, the program creates an instance of `MyClass` and calls `MyMethod()`.

If I need to run 10000 iterations, it would be like case #1 shown below (not exactly match, but the general idea is similar).

One of my coworkers told me my design doesn't make sense, and he prefers case #2 below. He believes it would increase the overall performance, because there will be less memory and less processing time with just 1 global instance.

I am unsure if he's exactly right... and I don't understand in general which case is better. I personally feel case #2 might not be a significant improvement and might mess up the program's overall design, but my knowledge is very limited, so I am here to look for your help. Any advice or tip would be super helpful. Thank you in advance!

```
class MyClass()
{
      public viod MyMethod() {...}
}
```

Case #1:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
      myClass.MyMethod();
}
```

Case #2:

```
public MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
...
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
      myClass.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: *"he prefers"* - That alone doesn't justify the change. What really matters is whether it's okay for the instance's state to be used for every method call, or if you need to start with fresh state for each call. That will depend on what `MyMethod` does.

Comment: It depends. If you're creating a bunch of different instances to represent different sets of data, then the first option would probably be the best. However, in this specific example you're creating a new instance, calling a method, then instantly throwing it away. This is extremely bad for performance and there's no reason to do it because no data is changing. In this case the second option would be better. The best option would probably be to just make this method static so you don't have to create an instance at all.

Comment: Does MyMethod change any instance variables of MyClass ?

Comment: Jesse said *"because no data is changing"* but we don't actually know that yet because you haven't posted the full definitions of the salient parts of class. It wouldn't be safe to assume, based on what you *have* posted, that `MyMethod` is the only thing in the class. The real code (rather than the minimal version you posted) might have state that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

A generally good rule of thumb is to do whichever you feel is more readable. For now. If you encounter issues with performance, then profile your app. If such profiling determines that this is where the bottleneck is occurring, then you could measure the time it takes to do either option mentioned above. Pick the faster one. Measure performance again and see if it helped.

In sum: do whichever one you feel is better until you NEED to optimize. Don’t do premature optimization. Writing for readability is often better than writing for performance, UNLESS performance becomes an issue.